# How to solve SSL certificate error

Tags: python, python-3.x

We are just hitting the url using

```
finalurl="http://www.myurl.com"
req=urllib.request.Request(finalurl)
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
```

we get output as:

```
ssl certificate error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use verify as 'False' as quick hack:

```
requests.get('https://www.myurl.com', verify=True)
```

Or use [SSL Cert Verification](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

```
requests.get('https://github.com', verify='/path/to/certfile')
```

Comment: I've tried it doesn't work, plus it gives many different errors. Try for http://jchartco.com/ , because this is causing the SSL certificate error.

Comment: @A.Info You are using urllib.request. I am using http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/